# Direct Collocation/Direct Transcription with a Multibody Plant

Tags: drake

I'm trying to do trajectory optimization for a custom robot I've specified with an sdf file.

I'd like to use direct collocation, but when I try to create the MultibodyPlant with time_step=0.0 I fail with a segfault. It works just fine when I use discrete time (e.g. Multibodyplant(time_step=.005).

However, if I use discrete time, the state is no longer continuous so I can't use direct collocation. So I tried to use direct transcription and I get the error

```
SystemExit: Failure at bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/systems/framework/_virtual_includes/context/drake/systems/framework/context.h:111 in num_total_states(): condition 'num_abstract_states() == 0' failed.
```

I think the reason is that DirectTranscription does not have a `assume_non_continuous_states_are_fixed`, the same issue as in this question: [direct transcription for compass gait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212887/direct-transcription-for-compass-gait). So maybe the easiest solution to my problem is to request this feature..

Comment: > but when I try to create the MultibodyPlant with time_step=0.0 I fail with a segfault.

That sounds real bad. Would it be possible to have a minimum snippet that reproduces the problem and open an issue on Github? either we have a bug, or at least we should be reporting a better error message? unless the bug is on the client code

Comment: Sure, here's an issue I opened with a code snippet: https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/13678

Comment: Looks like the code declares the MultibodyPlant to be continuous but then tries to access discrete state variables (which there aren't any). Try accessing the continuous state variables instead.

Comment: Ah I understand. Thanks for getting back to me so quickly.

Comment: I also agree that asking for `assume_non_continuous_states_are_fixed` to be implemented in `DirectTranscription` is a completely reasonable request, and may be needed here.  Please do open a drake issue about it if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommended above that we *do* add that `assume_non_continuous_states_are_fixed` to `DirectTranscription`.  But the reason that this option was not implemented already is a little subtle, so I’ll add it here.

It’s not actually `MultibodyPlant` that is adding the abstract state, but `SceneGraph`.  For dynamics/planning, you only need `SceneGraph` if you are relying on contact forces in your dynamics.  For acrobots / cart-poles, etc, you can already use a `MultibodyPlant` with `DirectTranscription` by passing the MBP only (no `SceneGraph`) to the optimization.  And for systems that *do* make and break contact, I would have said that `DirectTranscription` might not be the algorithm you want; although there are no hard and fast rules saying it won’t work.  It’s just that you’ll end up with stiff differential equations which are hard to transcribe in a reasonable trajectory optimization that doesn’t reason explicitly about the contact.

I think I know your application, which involves wheels that are in contact and stay in contact.  That means that you do need `SceneGraph`.  That might be a case were this currently missing combination makes perfect sense, and we should add it.